# How to convert blob into byteArray in flask python?

Tags: python, arrays, blob, data-conversion

A customer sends a multipart file to me, I read it with:

```
    blob = request.files['file'].read()
```

I have a blob file in hand. Now I have to send this file with requests like `open('file.png', 'rb')`. How can I convert `blob` to something like `rb` mode. With `open` I could not open blob directly.

The below code did not work:

```
opened_file = open(request.files['file'], 'rb')
```

And I got the following error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FileStorage found
```

Is there a way to do that **without saving it on file system**? I send my requests to somewhere else:

```
files = dict({'file': byteArrayFile})
r = requests.post(self.url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.files['file']` is already a file-like object (it's [a `FileStorage` instance](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage)), so you can use that directly; you don't need to `open` it.

```
r = requests.post(self.url, files={"file": request.files["file"]}, headers=headers)
```

You can think of a file-like object as an open file. They behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

it worked for me and for testing if you wish to have a look on the images try

```
img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image is stored in a Blob format (i.e. in a database) you can use the same technique explained by Billal Begueradj to convert your image from Blobs to a byte array.

In my case, I needed my images where stored in a blob column in a db table:

```
def select_all_X_values(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT ImageData from PiecesTable")    
    rows = cur.fetchall()    
    return rows
```

I then created a helper function to change my dataset into np.array:

```
X_dataset = select_all_X_values(conn)
imagesList = convertToByteIO(np.array(X_dataset))

def convertToByteIO(imagesArray):
    """
    # Converts an array of images into an array of Bytes
    """
    imagesList = []

    for i in range(len(imagesArray)):  
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(imagesArray[i])).convert("RGB")
        imagesList.insert(i, np.array(img))

    return imagesList
```

After this, I was able to use the byteArrays in my Neural Network.

```
plt.imshow(imagesList[0])
```